# How does Kotlin know how to carry out the plus operator

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, you can use the plus sign to combine a number of contexts:

```
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, exception ->
    println(exception.message)
}

val threadPool = Dispatchers.IO
val job = Job()

GlobalScope.launch(exceptionHandler + threadPool + job) {
    throw Exception("Bad robot")
}
```

I'm use to seeing the plus sign used for adding numbers or joining strings together. But apparently it can be used for other things as well. How does Kotlin know how to perform an operation on some arbitrary object using the plus sign?

If I look at the documentation for Collections, it shows an example of where a + or - sign can be used to merge or remove items from collections:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-plus-minus.html

That implies that Kotlin must somehow have to know how to carry out the operation of adding or removing items to a collection. I assume that if I wanted to create my own overload for + or -, I would have to define it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is just an operator which calls special method of class: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html
For different classes this method does different things such as adding numbers, concatenating strings, etc.

You can apply your own implementation of operators for custom classes.

Comment: There's nothing in that link that shows the example I have provided. They just show examples like +a, a++. The plus sign is clearly bound to the type whereas the example I gave show a space on both sides of the + with no indication as to what type it is bound to. I am quite certain that this has nothing to do with overloading. It appears to be something specific to collections as indicated here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-plus-minus.html

Comment: @AndroidDev For binary operations like `+` method is called for left-hand type as it is described in the link: `a + b` is equal to call `a.plus(b)`

Comment: In your example method plus of class CoroutineExceptionHandler is called as exceptionHandler object has this type. And than method plus is called again for second + operator.

Comment: You're right. Buried in the source code for CoroutineExceptionHandler is: public override fun plus(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineContext = context